# How can I add knowledge of namespaces before I deserialize XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I've found several examples of creating XmlSerializerNamespaces and adding 1 to many namespaces, then serializing based on the object and the list of namespaces.

I can't find any examples of where I have an XML string and I need to deserialize and I want to utilize the namespaces.  I've tried reading the string into an XmlTextReader and then setting the Namespaces property to true, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces are part of the XML document already and when deserializing them should be populated automatically.

The `Namespaces` property is by default set to true, so no need to set it to true again - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.namespaces.aspx).

Can you post your code and XML?

Comment: I think this is where I was getting confused.  The transaction that comes into my web service starts as <tx:Request ...

My schema is defined as:

<xsd:complexType name="Request">
                <xsd:complexContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="tx:Request_Type">

I'm assuming that even though I'm extending the "tx:Request_Type", the top level request needs to be defined as "tx:Request" (in order to match how the transaction is being sent).